# Error to create a disk in google compute (The resource '... diskTypes/{pd-ssd}' was not found

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I try to create a disk in Google Compute. This is the process and error:

```
gcloud compute disks create test --type={pd-ssd}

    For the following disks:
 - [test]
choose a zone:
 [1] asia-east1-a
 [2] asia-east1-c
 [3] asia-east1-b
 [4] europe-west1-c
 [5] europe-west1-b
 [6] europe-west1-d
 [7] us-central1-a
 [8] us-central1-b
 [9] us-central1-c
 [10] us-central1-f
Please enter your numeric choice:  9

NAME ZONE SIZE_GB TYPE STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.disks.create) Some requests did not succeed:
 - The resource 'projects/devco-979/zones/us-central1-c/diskTypes/{pd-ssd}' was not found
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the output of `gcloud compute disk-types list --zone us-central1-c`?

Comment: This is the output: $ gcloud compute disk-types list --zone us-central1-c
NAME        ZONE          VALID_DISK_SIZES
pd-standard us-central1-c 10GB-10240GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the braces:

```
gcloud compute disks create test --type=pd-ssd
```

---

**Edit:**

Based on the output you gave for gcloud compute disk-types list, you don't have access to pd-ssd drives. Usually this is because you are still on the free tier. If you upgrade to paid service, you will get access to pd-ssd drives.

Comment: Yes @stepen-weinberg , I needed update my account to "pay after free tier". I created an account over "300 usd for three months".  Do you know if 300 usd will be lost?

Comment: The $300 is not lost.